# Optimizing redundant logical tests on constants in Python

Tags: python, optimization, refactoring

Let's assume I have a main function that performs a boolean logical test to decide to run 1 of 2 subfunctions, function A or function B.  The main function is looped through 1 billion times, but the value for the logical test is a constant (it's input by the user at program initiation).

I see 2 possible ways to write this:
1) Bury the logical test in function A.  At least in theory, the logical test would have to be performed 1 billion times, which doesn't sound efficient.
2) Do the logical test before the main function.  Split the main function into main function 1 and main function 2 (which are identical except for which subfunction they run), and use the logical test to decide which main function to run.  Here, the logical test is only performed once, but this implementation creates redundant code.

Is there any difference in computational efficiency between implementations 1) and 2)?  In other words, does Python do any automatic optimization to make these two implementations equivalent at the machine code level?

Comment: I suggest you can timeit yourself: http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: Python doesn't do any kind of optimization you are thinking of. Furthermore, if one billion simple if statements is what can cause your code to slow down, then you aren't doing anything interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @mmgp is right on both counts -- CPython doesn't do any such optimizations, and this is very unlikely to be a bottleneck in the sort of codes Python is good at -- there is a third option.  You can pass the function you want to use as a parameter:

```
>>> def g1():
...         print 'g1'
...     
>>> def g2():
...         print 'g2'
...     
>>> def subfunc(fn):
...         fn()
...     
>>> def caller(a):
...         f = g1 if a else g2
...         for i in range(2):
...                 subfunc(f)
...         
>>> caller(True)
g1
g1
>>> caller(False)
g2
g2
```

Your subfunction can stay exactly the same, and you've hoisted the test out of the loop.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of "best practice" answer I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: You should specify that, while CPython doesn't do any bytecode optimization or machine-code generation, the other implementations of Python (IronPython, Jython, PyPy) use a JIT compiler and could conceivably optimize this check away under the right conditions. That said, passing in a callable is the right approach to optimization here.

Comment: Of course PyPy (and maybe the others) will make a trivial loop so fast that it's hard to actually test…

Answer (score 1):

As Patashu suggests, let's use `timeit` to test instead of trying to guess. I'll use the magic `%timeit` in `ipython`, since it's even simpler. Here's the code:

```
In [275]: def ff(): pass

In [276]: def ft(): pass

In [277]: def f1(b): # naive implementation
   .....:     for i in range(1000000):
   .....:         if b: ft()
   .....:         else: ff()

In [278]: %timeit f1(True)
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop

In [279]: def f2(b): # DSM's implementation
   .....:     f = ft if b else ff
   .....:     for i in range(1000000):
   .....:         f()

In [280]: %timeit f2(True)
10 loops, best of 3: 99.2 ms per loop
```

So, it is a bit faster, at least in CPython 3.3.0 64-bit on my Mac.

However, if you know anything about Python optimization, you'll probably notice that this is about the same performance gain you'd expect just from moving a global variable to local. So, let's take that out of the equation by doing the same thing without hoisting the boolean expression:

```
In [277]: def f3(b): # Just local binding, no if hoisting
   .....:     f, g = ft, ff
   .....:     for i in range(1000000):
   .....:         if b: f()
   .....:         else: g()
In [286]: %timeit f3(True)
10 loops, best of 3: 94.8 ms per loop
```

I put together a [more complete test](http://pastebin.com/00FPQgcf), including the OP's intended optimization, and code that works in 3.x and 2.x without change, and ran it against Apple 2.7.2, python.org 3.3.0, PyPy 1.9.0/2.7.2, and Jython 2.5.2 (all 64-bit builds on a Mac, and then just using Cython 0.17.1 pyximport (under Python 3.3.0) to compile the same source as Cython code:

```
                 3.3.0   2.7.2   PyPy    Jython  Cython
orig             1.136   1.519   0.091   1.680   0.448
OP optimization  1.119   1.362   0.034   1.613   0.460
rebinding        0.936   1.369   0.030   1.492   0.137
DSM version      0.936   1.329   0.031   1.523   0.138
```

So, it looks like binding the names outside the loop gives a speed boost of somewhere between 1.1x and 3x; additionally hoisting the comparison out of the loop may give you another 3% or so—but all of this is nothing compared to using PyPy instead of CPython, Cython instead of Python, or even 3.x instead of 2.x. Writing actual Cython or custom C code, or moving the loop into `numpy`, would be even faster.

And if you think about it, this makes sense. If the cost of a billion bool comparisons or global lookups matters, the cost of a billion function calls and a billion loops through the interpreter are going to matter far more. If you're not bothering to optimize that out (and you can often do that just by using a generator expression, list comprehension, `map` call, etc. in place of a loop, even if switching interpreters, rewriting your code around `numpy`, etc. aren't feasible), you shouldn't be worrying about the small stuff.

And obviously, if that last 3% ever really does make a difference, you'll need to perform more realistic tests, on the platforms you actually care about.

It's probably worth using DSM's implementation—but because it's more idiomatic and easier to read, not because it may or may not be faster.

Comment: You'll note I didn't use the word "optimization" referring to my answer. :^)  The only reason I can think of to worry about this is if it made the code clearer.  Anything much more complicated than `pass` and I'd expect any (theoretical) benefits to be lost in the noise.